# Apache httpd - Updating return code when Location header is present

Tags: apache, return-code

We have a custom web application, which is setting Location header to redirect to a new page, but application is sending a return code of 200 (instead of 302). Browser is ignoring the Location header and does nothing due to return code 200.

Custom application is front-ended (reverse proxy) by Apache web server.

Is there any way to update return code in Apache to 302, where Location header is present and return code is 200?

Comment: what is your application sending to apache?  what interface are you using CGI? , fastCGI?

Comment: Custom application is written in Java. It should have set return code of 302 when Location header is set.

Comment: no. code comes before header.

Answer (score 1):

if you're sending the return code on the first line of the response like

`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved`

you're doing everything right.

if you can't send the HTTP code perhaps you can get the effect you want with a refresh header.

Comment: Thats the problem. We are getting 200, when 302 is expected. Checking to see if Apache can help updating the return code .

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need to send the correct code. I don't think apache can reinterpret the headers.  maybe use a refresh header?